# R - Compare lists and flag matches

Tags: r, list, loops, if-statement, match

I have 2 lists and I need to identify and then flag where there is a match between list 1 and list 2.

Example:

```
List 1  List 2
   1      1
   2      2
   3      3
   4      4
   5      5
   6    
   7    
   8    
   9    
  10
```

Desired Output:

```
List 1  Match
  1       Y
  2       Y
  3       Y
  4       Y
  5       Y
  6       N
  7       N
  8       N
  9       N
  10      N
```

I tried a combination of an if statement wrapped in a loop but that just produced negative result regardless of a match. Any help would be much appreciated!

My current approach:

```
for(x in 1:List1)) 

{

  if(List1[x] %in% List2 == TRUE) {
    List1$Match <- 'Yes'
  }else{
    List1$Match <- 'No'
  }

}
```

So I need to append the TRUE or FALSE to List 1

```
    > List1 %in% List2==TRUE
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

This did the trick can replace true false with Y and N:

```
List1$Match <- List1 %in% List2==TRUE
```

Comment: Are they `list`s or `vector`s in a `list`?

Comment: chr [1:10] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7" "8" "8" "10"

Comment: I think you are looking for `c("N", "Y")[(List1 == List2) + 1]`

Comment: No luck...if I can just make the TRUE and FALSE results append to List1 then we are there...

Comment: What do you mean by append to `List1`? `List1` is a vector. What are you trying to do? Do you want to replace the values in `List1`?

Comment: `List1$Match <- List1 %in% List2==TRUE` is awekword. Why not just `List1$Match <- List1 %in% List2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1 <- c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
list2 <- c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

result1 <- list1 %in% list2

result1 <- gsub("TRUE", "Y", result1)  
result1 <- gsub("FALSE", "N", result1)
```

Comment: Yep that's what I ended up with! Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Good answer, I took the liberty of editing your answer to add a data frame creation step, which was close to mine.  You were just a bit faster :-).  I interpreted @Methexis question as including the need to make a data frame containing the first list and a "Yes/No" match column.

Comment: @Methexis if you want to "append" the match, consider `df<-data.frame(list1, match=result1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`  I tried doing this as an edit, but that is apparently bad form, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need in using `gsub` twice, you can simply use indexing

```
List1 <- 1:10
List2 <- 1:5

c("N", "Y")[(List1 %in% List2) + 1]
## [1] "Y" "Y" "Y" "Y" "Y" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N"
```

Or even simpler

```
ifelse(List1 %in% List2, "Y", "N")
# [1] "Y" "Y" "Y" "Y" "Y" "N" "N" "N" "N" "N"
```